# Python SparseArray Dtype to Float

Tags: pandas, sparse-matrix

pandas: 1.1.2

How do you convert a sparsearray dtype to a float64 dtype?

```
df
         id  N_ERVisits  N_admission  N_diagnoses  N_hospDays  N_procedures
0      1         0.0          0.0     0.000090         0.0      0.000000
1      1         0.0          0.0     0.000000         0.0      0.000000
2      1         0.0          0.0     0.000000         0.0      0.000000
3      1         0.0          0.0     0.000800         0.0      0.000000
4      1         0.0          0.0     0.000000         0.0      0.000000

df.dtypes
id                         int64
N_ERVisits      Sparse[float64, 0]
N_admission     Sparse[float64, 0]
N_diagnoses     Sparse[float64, 0]
N_hospDays      Sparse[float64, 0]
N_procedures    Sparse[float64, 0]
dtype: object
```

I thought I would be able to a standard conversion:

```
df['N_ERVisits'] = df['N_ERVisits'].astype('float64')
df.dtypes
empi                           int64
N_ERVisits      Sparse[float64, 0.0]
N_admission       Sparse[float64, 0]
N_diagnoses       Sparse[float64, 0]
N_hospDays        Sparse[float64, 0]
N_procedures      Sparse[float64, 0]
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't need sparsity anymore, use `SparseArray.values.to_dense()` to convert the series into a dense numpy array. The `.astype()` function then works as expected.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# data
arr = np.zeros((100,))
arr[1] = 1
arr[10] = 10

df = pd.DataFrame(data={
    'id': np.array(range(1, 101)),
    'col1': pd.arrays.SparseArray(arr, fill_value=0)
})
# df["col1"].values.dtype == Sparse[float64, 0]

# sparsity retained (note the difference in fill_value)
df["col2"] = df["col1"].astype(pd.SparseDtype(np.float64))
df["col3"] = df["col1"].astype(np.float64)

# no sparsity
df["col4"] = df["col1"].values.to_dense().astype(np.float64)
print(df.dtypes)
```

Output:

```
id                     int64
col1      Sparse[float64, 0]
col2    Sparse[float64, nan]
col3    Sparse[float64, 0.0]
col4                 float64
dtype: object
```

The seemingly tricky phenomenon can be understood by the underlying object types of the column. One must call `.values` explicitly in order to work on the underlying `SparseArray` itself.

```
type(df["col1"])
Out[5]: pandas.core.series.Series

type(df["col1"].values)
Out[6]: pandas.core.arrays.sparse.array.SparseArray
```

N.B. My pandas version is 1.0.3 but the behavior should be identical.